# Unable to run junit plugin test Eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse, junit4, rcp

I have upgraded to Eclipse Mars for RCP from Luna. I have created a separate plugin project which contains all of my unit tests. If I run the plugin as a JUnit Plug-in Test I get the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication" could not be found in the registry.`

I am assuming I am missing some required plugins but I have no idea what these could be. I am using 32 bit Java 8 SDK and JUnit 4.8.1.

If I run the plugin as a JUnit Test, all tests that don't require RCP work, the other's fail because there is no workbench, which is what you would expect.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: you need the `org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime` plug-in available in your target platform to execute the tests.

---

A more-or-less generic approach to find who contributed some ids in Eclipse:

- In general, in the eclipse world ids are prefixed with the plug-in that contributes them.
- Looking at the list of plug-ins in the Plug-ins view, you find in the current case, that only a single plug-in is the prefix of the id you want.
- If you double-click it, the manifest editor opens and you can navigate to the Extensions page, where you find some `org.eclipse.core.runtime.application` extensions; one of them having the required `org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication` ID.